# Why would my parallel code be slower than my serial code?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, processing-efficiency

In general, is it possible for a parallel code to be slower than the serial code? mine is and I am really frustrated at it! what can I do?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, especially with small amount of computations. You can increase amount of computations between MPI calls, decrease number of barriers and make send/recv calls more syncronous. Please give more information about a porblem and make your question more constrictive.

Comment: Are you perchance running your parallel code on a computer with less cores than you have processes?

Comment: Bad parallelisation is worse than no parallelisation at all. You may freely cite me...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Among others, 3 key factors that determine the performance of the parallel model are:

- Parallel task granularity;
- Communication overhead;
- Load balancing among processes.

**Parallel task granularity**

The granularity of the parallel tasks must be big enough to overleap the overheads of the parallelism (*e.g.,* parallel task creation and communication between them). Because communication overhead is normally higher with processes in distributed memory (DM) models than thread synchronization, the processes should have a higher task granularity. This granularity also should not jeopardize the load balancing.

**tl;dr:** Your parallel tasks must be "big" enough to justify the overheads of parallelization.

---

**Communication overhead**

Whenever one process intends to communicate with others, it has the cost of creating/sending the message, and in the case of `synchronous communication` routines, there is also the cost of waiting for the other processes to receive the message. So to increase the performance of your application with MPI it is necessary to reduce the number of messages exchanged between processes.

You may use computational redundancy between processes, instead of waiting for the result from one particular process, this result can be performed directly in each process. Of course, this is normally justified when the overhead of exchanging the result overlaps the time taken by the computation itself. Another solution is to replace `synchronous communication` with `asynchronous communication`. While in `synchronous communication` the process that sends the message waits until the other process receives it, in `asynchronous communication` the process resumes its execution immediately after returning from the send call. Thus, overlapping communication with computation. However, to take advantage of `asynchronous communication` it may be necessary to rewrite the code, also it may still be hard to achieve a good overlap ratio.

It is possible to reduce communication overhead by using higher-performance communication hardware, but it may turn out expensive. Collective communications can also improve communication performance since it optimizes the communication based on the hardware, network, and topology.

**tl;dr:** Reduce the amount of communication and synchronization between parallel tasks. Using: redundant computation, asynchronous communications, collective communications, and faster communication hardware.

---

**Load balancing among processes**

A good load balancing is essential since it maximizes the work done in parallel. Load balancing is affected by both task distribution among processes and the set of resources that the application is running.

In applications running in a fixed set of resources, you should focus on the task distribution. If the tasks have roughly the same amount of computation (e.g., for iterations), then it is only necessary to perform the most equality distribution of tasks among processes.

But, some applications may run in systems with processors with different speeds or it may have sub-tasks with different amounts of computation. For this type of situation, to promote better load balancing, a task `farming model` can be used, since it can be implemented with a dynamic task distribution. However, in this model, the amount of communication used can jeopardize efficiency.

Another solution is to you manually perform tuning of the task distribution. This may turn out to be complex and hard. However, if the set of resources is not speed homogeneous and is constantly changing between application execution the performance portability of the task distribution tuning may be jeopardized.

**tl;dr:** Each process should take approximately the same time to finish their work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are several reasons why parallel code can be slower than serial code.

If you are doing matrix operations, you may want to look into utilizing cpu cache memory more effectively by 'blocking' code.You can potentially get up to 3 to 4 times performance improvements depending on cpu cache size. Blocking is essentially processing the matrices in small tiles or blocks such that they fit in the cache memory.  This reduces having to read/write main memory and results in performance improvements.

The other option is to use GPUs.

Above solutions work well where bulk of the computing is for floating point or integer operations

For general purpose computing, ideally you want to design your app to be adaptive such that at runtime it determines if there is a performance gain in distributing the work load and only distribute if it is advantageous.